# Pivot rows into columns in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a sample table that looks like this:

```
+------+-------------+---------+----------+
| Year |   Country   | Ranking | Category |
+------+-------------+---------+----------+
| 2018 | Ghana       |       1 | Swimming |
| 2018 | Sweden      |       2 | Swimming |
| 2018 | Costa Rica  |       3 | Swimming |
| 2018 | Jordan      |       1 | Sprint   |
| 2018 | Thailand    |       2 | Sprint   |
| 2018 | Finland     |       3 | Sprint   |
| 2018 | Myanmar     |       1 | Boxing   |
| 2018 | Peru        |       2 | Boxing   |
| 2018 | Belgium     |       3 | Boxing   |
| 2017 | Nigeria     |       1 | Swimming |
| 2017 | Philippines |       2 | Swimming |
| 2017 | Haiti       |       3 | Swimming |
| 2017 | Netherlands |       1 | Sprint   |
| 2017 | Macedonia   |       2 | Sprint   |
| 2017 | Kuwait      |       3 | Sprint   |
| 2017 | Malaysia    |       1 | Boxing   |
| 2017 | New Zealand |       2 | Boxing   |
| 2017 | Palau       |       3 | Boxing   |
+------+-------------+---------+----------+
```

and need to create  a report that looks like this:

```
+----------+---------+-------------+------------+
| Category | Ranking |    2017     |    2018    |
+----------+---------+-------------+------------+
| Swimming |       1 | Nigeria     | Ghana      |
| Swimming |       2 | Philippines | Sweden     |
| Swimming |       3 | Haiti       | Costa Rica |
| Sprint   |       1 | Netherlands | Jordan     |
| Sprint   |       2 | Macedonia   | Thailand   |
| Sprint   |       3 | Kuwait      | Finland    |
| Boxing   |       1 | Malaysia    | Myanmar    |
| Boxing   |       2 | New Zealand | Peru       |
| Boxing   |       3 | Palau       | Belgium    |
+----------+---------+-------------+------------+
```

I've searched for pivot samples, but all seem to use aggregate function that I do not think applies in my case.

This is where I am getting stuck with:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
   SELECT Category
         ,Country
         ,Ranking
         ,[Year]
   FROM table1
 ) AS SourceTable PIVOT(<b><font color="red"> ?? </font></b> FOR [Year] IN ([2017], [2018])) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: Try use MAX()..

Comment: Thank you so much.  That worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that conditional aggregation is the simplest way to achieve desired results.

You can group on `Category` and `Ranking`, then calculate 2017 and 2018 columns with a case statement and finally remove `null` values with `max`:

```
declare @tmp table ([Year] int, Country varchar(50), Ranking int, Category varchar(50))
insert into @tmp values
     (2018, 'Ghana'       ,1, 'Swimming')
    ,(2018, 'Sweden'      ,2, 'Swimming')
    ,(2018, 'Costa Rica'  ,3, 'Swimming')
    ,(2018, 'Jordan'      ,1, 'Sprint')
    ,(2018, 'Thailand'    ,2, 'Sprint')
    ,(2018, 'Finland'     ,3, 'Sprint')
    ,(2018, 'Myanmar'     ,1, 'Boxing')
    ,(2018, 'Peru'        ,2, 'Boxing')
    ,(2018, 'Belgium'     ,3, 'Boxing')
    ,(2017, 'Nigeria'     ,1, 'Swimming')
    ,(2017, 'Philippines' ,2, 'Swimming')
    ,(2017, 'Haiti'       ,3, 'Swimming')
    ,(2017, 'Netherlands' ,1, 'Sprint')
    ,(2017, 'Macedonia'   ,2, 'Sprint')
    ,(2017, 'Kuwait'      ,3, 'Sprint')
    ,(2017, 'Malaysia'    ,1, 'Boxing')
    ,(2017, 'New Zealand' ,2, 'Boxing')
    ,(2017, 'Palau'       ,3, 'Boxing')

select 
      Category
    , Ranking 
    , max(case when [year] = 2017 then country else null end) as [2017] 
    , max(case when [year] = 2018 then country else null end) as [2018] 
From @tmp
group by 
    Category, Ranking 
order by 
    Category desc, Ranking
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.  Didn't know there is another way of doing other than pivot.

Comment: You're welcome @EDREV ! By the way, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted.